# How does using sine averaged out the function?

Tags: integration, signal-processing, fluid-dynamics

For instance, by introducing a weighting function $a(t)$ such that
$$\langle U_\alpha(\vec{x},t)\rangle=\int^\infty_{-\infty}U_\alpha (\vec{x},t+s)a(s)ds$$
where $\int^\infty_{-\infty}a(t)dt=1$.
If we choose the weighting function to be:
$$a(t)=\frac{1}{\pi t}\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{\tau}\right)$$
Then the above equation will average out those frequencies which are greater than $\omega=\pi/\tau$.

I am trying to understand this intuitively or mathematically but I can't find anywhere to start from. How does the integral above filter out the high frequency components?

Comment: Use the fact that $\mathcal{F}(f \star g) = \mathcal{F}(f) \mathcal{F}(g)$ where $\star$ denotes convolution and $ \mathcal{F}(g)$ is the rect function. Take a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_filter

Comment: Good ways of developing intuition for these kinds of phenomena are to try plugging in various pure oscillations to see what happens, and remember that if you integrate values that oscillate around 0, they'll tend to average out to 0.

Answer (score -1):

As an illustration of how the filter works we can consider the function $U(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}e^{-\alpha x^2}\cos ax$ and integral
$$I(a,b)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty U(x)\frac{\sin bx}{x}dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}\cos ax\frac{\sin bx}{x}dx$$
We consider $\alpha$ as a small parameter ($\alpha\ll a,b$), and the function $e^{-\alpha x^2}$ is a smooth envelope function ensuring the convergence of the integral at infinity. At $\alpha\to0 \,\,e^{-\alpha x^2}\to 1$.

Using $\frac{\sin bx}{x}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-b}^b e^{itx}dt\,\,$ we can write
$$I(a,b)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2+iax}\int_{-b}^b e^{itx}dt\, dx$$
Changing the order of integration, making full square in the exponent power and integrating over $x$
$$I(a,b)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\Re\int_{-b}^b dt\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2+iax+itx} dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\Re\int_{-b}^b dt\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha\big( x^2-ix(a+t)/\alpha-(a+t)^2/4\alpha^2+(a+t)^2/4\alpha^2\big)} dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\Re\int_{-b}^b dt\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha\big( x-i(a+t)/2\alpha\big)^2}e^{-(a+t)^2/4\alpha} dx$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha}}\int_{-b}^be^{-(a+t)^2/4\alpha}dt=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha}}\int_{a-b}^{a+b}e^{-x^2/4\alpha}dx$$
At $\alpha\to 0$ the function $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha}}e^{-x^2/4\alpha}\,$ is almost zero everywhere, except for a narrow interval near $x=0$, where it has a sharp  peak. It is easy to check that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$, so at $\alpha\to 0\,\,f(x)\to \delta(x)$ - delta-function.

It follows that, up to exponentially small correction terms, $I(a,b)=1$, as soon as $a\in[-b, b]$, and is equal to zero otherwise.

Therefore, we have a filter that cuts out all oscillations with the frequencies higher than $b$. At  $\alpha\ll1$ (but $\neq0$) the filter is not ideal, so it not only cuts out the higher frequencies, but also changes the amplitude of the oscillations with the frequencies near the boundary $b$ (at $a\approx b$) - the perfect step-function becomes blurry at the edges.

At $\alpha=0$ the filter is ideal, and
$$I(a,b)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos ax\frac{\sin bx}{x}dx=1 \,\text{at} \,a\in[-b;b] \,\text {, and zero otherwise}$$
The last result can be obtained using the straightforward integration.